# Nib IBOutlet causes app to crash

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nib, iboutlet

Really need your help! I've been through every possible post addressing this issue and nothing seems to work.

So I'm using a .xib file to create a subview within ProfileFoldingCellView.swift, which works perfectly until I attempt to add an IBOutlet in the same class. Here's the code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ProfileFoldingCellView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var mainLabel: UILabel!
    public var cellIndex: Int = 0

    init(index: Int) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))

        cellIndex = index
        print("Index: \(cellIndex)")

        setupContentView()
    }

    func setupContentView() {
        let contentView = UINib(nibName: "ProfileFoldingCellView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

        addSubview(contentView)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupContentView()
    }

}
```

As you can see, the label IBOutlet is created without any issues and there are no other outdated or unused outlets roaming around.

[image: Label Outlet] https://i.stack.imgur.com/5y7Ra.jpg

I've also made sure to set ProfileFoldingCellView.swift as the file owner's class.

Everything runs perfectly until I link the outlet! Then I get this error:

[image: Error] https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROcr4.jpg

Trust me, I've tried everything. I've probably re-created the outlet a million times, nothing is working. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9):

Leave your File's Owner as `NSObject` and set your view class as `ProfileFoldingCellView`, your `mainLabel` should be connected to the `UIView` object and not `File's Owner`[image]

Comment: Ok, this is definitely a step in the right direction. No error, but now the .xib UIView isn't displaying.

Comment: Correction, it crashes with this error http://imgur.com/a/f7305. The command line just says "(lldb)"

Comment: Would you have a possible solution?

Comment: Man, I've been in this bug for 3 hours and you saved me. Damn it.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it!

I simply switched the line

```
let contentView = UINib(nibName: "ProfileFoldingCellView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
```

with the following:

```
let contentView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ProfileFoldingCellView", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! UIView
```

I kept the file owner's class as ProfileFoldingCellView

Answer (score 1):

According to the image you posted, your `mainLabel` outlet is not connected to the label... It's connected to the `files owner` object which is probably your cell view and not a `UILabel`.

Comment: I tried doing that, but now the .xib UIView isn't displaying.

Comment: What I would do in this case is create a nib file for the entire `UITableViewCell` and if you need your ProfileFoldingCellView you can build it in there.  UITableView includes `func register(_ nib: UINib?, 
forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)` which allows you to more easily register a nib to use to create table view cells.

Comment: Would this be the only solution?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is already mentioned in the upper section. I just want to illustrate it with images so that it can be more understandable.

Step1: Do not assign the class to the file owner and leave it as NSObject [image]

Step2: Select your main view and Assign the class to that view [image]

Step3: Now connect your outlet[image]

Now it will not cause any kind of error related to IBOutlet :)